# Build class structure for Hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Given below is my class structure I am trying to build a class which can 
store and  I can access the hierarchy of data given below.

To summarize in words (please see Hierarchy illustrated below after the code);
All Regions have only 1 Master Region
Under a Region there can be one or more Locations.

```
                     public class RegionLocItemView
                        {

                            public  Guid Id { get; set; }
                            public  string name { get; set; }
                            public  Guid value { get; set; }
                            public  bool isChecked { get; set; }
                            public List<RegionLocItemView> Children
                            {
                                get ; 
                                set
                                {
                                   //where do i set this from             

                                } ;
                            }
                            public RegionLocItemView(List<RegionLocItemView> a)
                            {
                                Children = a;
                            }

                            public RegionLocItemView()
                            {
                            }

                        } /// end of class                                  

                Accessing class from code below:                      

                var getAvailableLocations = Model.SessionProvider.GetAvailableLocations.Where(e => e.Location.Count >= 1);

                    Guid parentid = Guid.Empty;
                    RegionLocItemView cls = new RegionLocItemView();
                    List<RegionLocItemView> main =  new List<RegionLocItemView>();
                 foreach (var a in getAvailableLocations)
                        {
                            if (a.ParentID == null)
                            {
                                //found Parent of all regions.
                                //cls = new RegionLocItemView();
                                cls.Id = a.ID;
                                parentid = a.ID;
                                cls.name = a.RecordName;
                                //main.Add(cls);
                                // break;
                            }

                            if (a.ParentID == parentid)
                            {
                                RegionLocItemView cls1 = new RegionLocItemView();
                                //found children
                                cls1.Id = a.ID;
                                parentid = a.ID;
                                cls1.name = a.RecordName;
                                cls.Children.Add(new List<RegionLocItemView>(cls1));  

                            }
                        }
```

I need to have an IEnumerable collection List to stored objects in the hierarchy below.

```
                    Main                     
                       Region1                  
                           Location1                
                           Location2           
                           Location3               
                       Region2                 
                            LocationA            
                            LocationB            
                            LocationC             
                        Region...                   
                            Location...
```

Questions:

Can you refactor my class structure above for the data above, and provide me with a code     sample of how I can access the class in C# code.  I am reading the above data from an         IEnumerable collection and the data is not arranged well and hence I need to do the above.

Why do I want this class structure: I want this so that I can bind this to a Telerik TreView control that accepts an IEnumerable collection like a Generic List.

Comment: Please fix your formatting into something readable.

Comment: @millimoose : Where you able to review the code. Any suggestion are welcome. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the generic framework classes can do the job

```
public class Main : Dictionary<Region, List<Location>> { }
```

Comment: public class Main : Dictionary<Region, List<Location>> { //what are the attributes here }  I was expecting a refactor my class so that I can accomodate that format.